# Are the two vectors span plane or line?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are the following vectors span plane or lines.

$V_1=$
\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
2\\
2
\end{bmatrix}

$V_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
6\\
3\\
3
\end{bmatrix}
$

It seem to me like they are a line beause  V1 times $\frac{3}{2}$ equal vector 2 so that makes it a multiple of vector 1.

Comment: I am puzzled. You already have the (correct) answer. So why ask the question?

Comment: I was not sure if my idea was correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two vectors are linearly dependent, then they can be thought of as different scalar multiples of the same vector.  Thus, the two of them together are still just a one-dimensional object.

In this case, since we can write v_1 = (2/3)*v_2 then we see that the two vectors are indeed linearly dependent.  So yes, in this case these two vectors are part of the span of the same line in R^3.

Comment: Yes that seem to make sense.